# Mojave: Is there a way to stop or delay the sorting of items in the finder using list or column view?

Tags: finder, mojave, macos, animation

Looooooong time Mac user.

I have a particular older system I use for cataloging items.

I get a folder of 50+ items, then have to manually rename each item. Batch renaming isn't useful and would actually be *more* work because there's little to no commonality between the files. I do have, run, and love A Better Finder Rename, but even that isn't useful for this process 90% of the time.

In Yosemite's Finder (column view), I could rename a file then hit <kbd>Return</kbd> and *quickly* hit the <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> key to move to the next file. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, rename and quickly hit <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>... repeat. This had a benefit of keeping the active file focused in the relevant list of items where I needed to be. If I paused for a few seconds before hitting return in the next file, *then* the list would re-sort. But I had roughly 5 seconds to enter renaming mode on the next file before re-sorting occurred.

In Yosemite, after about 20-30 files I'd have to relaunch the Finder due to some cache that started getting bogged down. Renaming and cursor movements would start getting delayed - the more I files I renamed the longer the delay would become. Relaunch Finder.. all back to 100% speed. I learned to live with this.

I recently upgraded this system to Mojave, as far as it can go. In Mojave's Finder (column or list view), as soon as I rename a file and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> the file instantly moves to re-sort based upon its new name. *No matter how fast* I hit the arrow keys, the file moves. I've searched and searched for a way to delay or turn off this "instant resort" behavior and I've come up with nothing. I've turned off (reduced) animations, etc and there's been no change.

---

**Is there a way in Mojave's Finder to manually rename a list of files *without* the files instantly moving to re-sort based upon their new name?** Some sort of "delayed re-sort"?

---

I can't use icon view, it's too cumbersome. And the insta-move behavior seems to happen in column and list view equally. I've tried grouping by various things, but since the files are all the same "type/kind" and created at relatively the same date, and the name is changing, the file still *always* move to some degree.

Comment: I remember that - I think it was a bug… which you appear to have nicely exploited. I don't think it was ever intentional, it was just the Finder being really slow to catch up. Wish you luck, though. If you click the next file you need without 'closing' the rename, then it will select & apply your change. idk a way to do it with the keyboard though.

Comment: Hmm.. darn.. clicking won't help much. Benefit of the Yosemite behavior is that it was 100% keyboard, no clicking. I'm finding in Mojave I have to rename.. then hit the first letter of *where I was in the list* to move back to that area of the list... then arrow keys to navigate up/down.

Comment: What about using the list view and sorting by a different column, say, the file size? Renaming won't change the order then and since you say there's little commonality it doesn't sound like sorting by name would be that great a benefit.

Comment: Yeah. I have a Mojave machine right here. I can repro your described behaviour exactly. The 'click on next required' does work, but yup, you have to keep swapping between mouse & keyboard. @DarkDust - I'd considered that, but I'm presuming there's something alphabetical about the required sequence of renames [idk for sure though]

Comment: Good idea with different groups but.. then thing is the dates and kind are all relatively similar.. size is too broad (100mb to 1mb) then sorted by name. "Name" is the section sort item for *any* of the group by items. So even if they stay sorted by size... they move because the name changed. I've not found any "group by" setting that does *not* move files after renaming.

Comment: Do you **need** groups? Otherwise other sort methods could work. Right click any column header & see what it lets you use for that file type - then clicking that header will sort by it. e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFvdq.png

Comment: I have found that if I hit Return then, within like milliseconds hit the down arrow... that works.. but I really do mean milliseconds or nanoseconds. Too fast to really be useful. I don't *need* Groups... I've simply explored them in the hopes of something working. So far, no luck.

Comment: I'm on SSDs here, I can just about hit the two keys as a simultaneous chord & it still won't emulate the Yosemite behaviour.

Comment: Okay @Tetsujin that image helped.. you're in **list view**... In list view, if sorted by something like "size", files won't move. This won't work in Column view. This is somewhat helpful, not ideal because some names are similar and I used to opt/arrow to select and copy to paste when renaming other files. But... it's still better than the instant re-sorting.

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer... `:)`

Comment: Yeah - I actually always use List rather than column for photos - I sort recent edits to the top that way so 'next process' is in easy reach

Comment: I can switch to list view for this folder of stored new files... I always move them all after renaming anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion…
If you use List view rather than Column, then you can add extra columns allowing you to sort by various non-standard parameters, which could result in your chosen sort *not* changing with a simple file rename.

I tend to use date modified for my photos - a name change does not qualify as a 'modification' so things will stay where they are after a rename.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Sorting by `size` seems to work here for my files. Few are the exact same kbs.

Comment: Excellent. For photos, as I always retain the original DSC name [DSD, E etc as each camera passes the next 10,000 mark] it means I can title files following that number & they don't move, even sorted alphabetically. I know you do graphics, so perhaps that's not as valid in your case, but it works for me.

Comment: Yeah my file names are wildly different,  but dates, time, kind are all very similar. Overall I'm finding the Mojave Finder.. well.. less ideal. But we'll see.

Comment: I've kind of forgotten what things were like before - I've been on Mojave since it came out [& am now stuck on it, with a house-full of big ol' Mac Pros.;)

Comment: I've been using Yosemite.. only upgraded to Mojave last week because of that web certificate *every site on earth apparently uses* expiring and preventing access to many sites (including Stack). :) To be honest.. CS6 and Yosemite is the bees knees.... if not for planned obsolescence.

Comment: Ah… yeah - again, i haven't seen CS since CC came out, though I do tend to lag about half a year behind, always let the newest version stabilise.